# IE7 asp.net mvc loading error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

We are facing a problem using Internet Explorer 7.
In ASP.NET MVC 3 the result page looks like:

```
<button type="button" onclick=" ShowOperation('/Page/Box/ShowOperation/CreateBox', '') ">...
```

and the error (in IE7 only) looks like:

```
Error: The value of the property 'ShowOperation' is null or undefined, not a Function object.
```

This function has been defined in file page.js which we attach externally

```
function ShowOperation(operationUrl, type) {
  if (type && type == 'download') {

    var temp = $("#pageGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

    if(temp.length == 0) {
        ProceedAjax(operationUrl, AjaxWarning);
        return;
    }

    $("#doOperation").attr("action", operationUrl);
    var uu = operationUrl.split("/");
    var action = uu[uu.length-1];
    $("#doOperationAction").val(action);
    $("#doOperationIds").val(temp);
    $("#doOperation").submit();
    return;
  }

  ProceedAjax(operationUrl, AjaxError);
  return;
}
```

Comment: this seems like an undefined function in Javascript

Comment: Where is the **JavaScript** method `ShowOperation` coming from?

Comment: add this 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7;"/> on your master page.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7;"/> unfortunately did not work

Answer (score 2):

Since the function is defined in another js file, you need to add `javascript:` before the function name while calling in onclick.
Your updated code would look somehow like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript: ShowOperation('/Page/Box/ShowOperation/CreateBox', '');">
```